# Is there a difference between returning an intermediate variable and returning a function call directly?

Tags: c++, runtime

Is there any difference between calling a function in `return`, and calling the function and then `return`ing the value on runtime, like this:

my functions prototypes:

```
int aFunc(int...);
int bFunc(int...);
```

my first bFunc return line:

```
int bFunc(int...)
{
  ...
  return (aFunc(x,...));
}
```

my second bFunc return line:

```
int bFunc(int...)
{
  ...
  int retVal = aFunc(x,...);
  return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using c++ language

Comment: For an `int` return type there should be no difference.  It gets messy in C++ if you're returning an object (and not simply an object pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good compiler should make both identical (at least when optimizations are enabled).

Theoretically, there are two copy operations in `bFunc`:

1. Into a local variable on the stack.
2. From the local variable, into the "bottom" of the stack (bottom in the perspective of `bFunc`).

If `retVal` is an object (class or structure) returned by-value and not by-reference (as in the case above), then the additional copy operation might yield an overhead proportional to the size of `retVal`.

In addition to that, the fact that the copy constructor should be called twice (when dealing with an object), might prevent the compiler from applying the optimization in the first place.

Comment: I've got a feeling someone's gonna steal that green V up there

Answer (score 6):

To answer your specific question: there should not be an observable difference between

```
return expression;
```

and

```
x = expression;
return x;
```

provided of course that `x` is of the correct type.

However, in C++ there can be a difference between

```
return complicated_expression;
```

and

```
x = some_subexpression;
y = some_other_subexpression;
return complicated_expression_rewritten_in_terms_of_x_and_y;
```

The reason being: C++ guarantees that destructors of temporary values created during the evaluation of a subexpression are run at the end of the *statement*. This refactoring moves the side effect of any temporary value destructor associated with `some_expression` from *after* the computation of `some_other_subexpression` -- at the end of the `return` statement - to *before* it - at the end of the assignment to `x`.

I have seen real-world production code where this refactoring introduced a bug into the program: the computation of `some_other_subexpression` depended for its correctness on the side effect of the destructor of a temporary value generated during the evaluation of `some_subexpression` running afterwards. The rewritten code was easier to read, but unfortunately also wrong.

Comment: Wow. I never looked at it that way. I am guessing that this is immaterial for language like C# as it is memory managed, correct?

Comment: that's insane. Were you the one who did troubleshooting and found the bug? I would never even think that simplifying an expression can change the behavior. I must say, I have a lot of respect who has to use C++ as their main language everyday. It's like they are working in Afghanistan, trying to avoid minefields everywhere and here I am, sitting in NYC, doing the best work of my life using C#. Thank you and the whole developer tools division for making our lives so much better.

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Well the situation is in some ways better and in some ways worse in C#. In C# the rules for finalizers are a bit crazy; you don't know if or when a finalizer is going to run, it runs on its own thread, a finalizer can run on objects whose ctors failed, or while control is still in the ctor (!) and so on. But finalizers are also much more rare in C# than in C++, and most of the time the Disposable pattern and `using` statement can be used to make the code sensible. But then again, the crazy scenario I describe in C++ is also rare. Which is worse is arguable. :-)

Comment: @SolutionYogi: The bug I allude to was due to a perfectly sensible-looking refactoring in some code inside the Coverity analyzer; I did not catch it. It might have been caught by running the analyzer on itself; I don't recall the details. A description of the bug and the fix was sent around and I made a note of it as something to look out for. My C++ skills are pretty rusty and every little bit helps. It can indeed feel like a minefield! I'm glad you like C# and I am proud to have been a part of it.

Comment: Exactly. I haven't written a finalizer even once and I have been using C# for last 8 years. And I am a believer in refactoring and I have definitely refactored code to simplify an overly complicated expression and I never worried that it would change the semantics, relying on the fantastic type system provided by C# and CLR. On this note, I often wonder where can C# go from here. The only thing I can think of is built in immutability support in the language and runtime.  You should write about some of the big theme ideas (like LINQ/ async/await) which you wish C# could have.

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Better immutability guarantees would be nice. Contracts that go beyond method signatures would be nice. The language ensures that you call a constructor before you use an object, but it doesn't ensure that you open a socket before you close it. Metaprogramming would be nice. There are lots of places C# *could* go from here, but it shouldn't evolve just for the sake of change.

Comment: Yes, contracts to enforce semantics would be amazing. E.g. I should be able to design a ASP.NET templating engine where I can enforce that all strings have been escaped properly before outputting it to browser. I know Scala allows you to implement something like that. Are there any other languages you know which are very powerful in their capabilities but not that mainstream?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a difference if the return type is something more complex like `std::vector`, depending on the optimizations implemented in the compiler.

Returning an unnamed vector requires (anonymous) *return value optimization* to avoid a copy, a common optimization. Whereas returning a named value requires ***named*** return value optimization, something [not all compilers did in the past](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The Visual C++ 8.0 compiler ... adds a new feature: Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO). NRVO eliminates the copy constructor and destructor of a stack-based return value. This optimizes out the redundant copy constructor and destructor calls and thus improves overall performance.

Comment: but if the return type is not a complex type, it isn't being a difference or it's still been depending on the optimizations implemented in the compiler ?

Comment: @TunahanÇATAK It depends on compiler/platform calling conventions that dictate how many registers can be used for a function return value. See http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf‎

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd not expect any real difference since the compiler may optimize the temporary variable away.